# Making paste command read from standard input

Tags: linux, shell, paste

```
$paste num let
1    a
2    b
3    c
4    d
```

So when I do

```
$ cat num | paste - - 
1    2
3    4
```

My question is why doesn't "`cat num | paste - -`" generate the output as:

```
1     1
2     2
3     3
4     4
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Clearly, `paste` reads a line from the first 'file' (which is standard input), and then a line from the second 'file' (which is also standard input) and pastes them to create the first line of output.  Then it repeats.

The POSIX specification for [`paste`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/paste.html) covers the point explicitly:

> If '`-`' is specified for one or more of the files, the standard input shall be used; the standard input shall be read one line at a time, circularly, for each instance of '`-`'.

Answer (score 1):

```
t1=$(cat 1.txt)
t2=$(cat 2.txt)
echo "$t1"  | paste - <(echo "$t2")
```

GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

：）

Comment: The question is explicitely about using pipes. Reading everything into memory should be avoided. Downvote. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You could use "`paste num num`" to generate

```
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
```

Comment: Although true, that isn't quite an answer to the question, is it?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstand this problem.